# Getting value of specific time in next week

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to get the value of next week ( + 7 days) at 09:00. I can get the Date using

```
 new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7)
```

For example, it returns: `1619343639426`

which translates to

```
new Date(1619343639426)
Sun Apr 25 2021 15:10:39 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

I want to get the value for `Sun Apr 25 2021 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

**how to do that ?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Comment: @Christopher: I want to jump to specific time of next week. I can jump  7 days but I want to be at `09:00`

Comment: To set the time for a date to 9am you can use [`date.setHours(9, 0, 0, 0);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours).

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7)).setHours(9, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Don't forget to set the milliseconds to 0 also. It's not very efficient to create 3 separate Date object, likely it's more efficient to use `let d = new Date(); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7); d.setHours(9,0,0,0)`.